# The linearity of $D \beta : \mathbb{E_1} \times \mathbb{E_2} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{E_1} \times \mathbb{E_2},F)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $\mathbb{E_1}, \mathbb{E_2}$ and $\mathbb{F}$ normed spaces of finite dimensions and $\beta : \mathbb{E_1} \times \mathbb{E_2} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is one bilinear function.
Then $D \beta : \mathbb{E_1} \times \mathbb{E_2} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{E_1} \times \mathbb{E_2},F)$ is linear.

Wanted to show that: $D\beta(x+y) = D\beta(x) + D\beta(y)$, where $D\beta(x+y), D\beta(x)$ and $D\beta(y)$ are bilinear functions are derived for functions, i.e, $D\beta(x)(a+b) = D\beta(x)(a) + D\beta(x)(b)$.

Comment: It may be better to write $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)$ instead of $x+y$ (maybe not, but it's worth thinking about anyway). The first task would be to determine $D\beta(x_1,x_2)$. Then it follows rather easily.

Comment: Note that I am not wanting the linearity of $D\beta(x_1,x_2)$ because it is true, i.e, $D\beta(x_1,x_2)$ is bilinear when applied. I do not know how to deal with the function $D\beta$ which is an application that takes into bilinear transformations.

Comment: Linear, not bilinear. $D\beta(x_1,x_2) \colon E_1\times E_2 \to F$ is linear, and $D\beta \colon E_1\times E_2 \to \mathcal{L}(E_1\times E_2,F)$ is also linear. The former by definition of the derivative, and the latter is what you want to show. Start by writing down which linear map $D\beta(x_1,x_2)$ is. $D\beta(x_1,x_2)\colon (y_1,y_2) \mapsto \text{ ?}$

Comment: Yes, $D\beta(x_1,y_1)$ is linear by definition.

Comment: Please, write down the map that $D\beta(x_1,x_2)$ is. $D\beta(x_1,x_2) \colon (h_1,h_2) \mapsto abcd$. The linearity of $D\beta \colon (x_1,x_2) \mapsto D\beta(x_1,x_2)$ becomes obvious then.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $D\beta(x_1,y_1)(\xi , \eta)=\beta(\xi, y_1) + \beta(x_1,\eta)$ and $D\beta(x_2,y_2)(\xi , \eta)=\beta(\xi, y_2) + \beta(x_2,\eta)$.

Then we have $D\beta(x_1 + x_2,y_1+ y_2)(\xi , \eta)=\beta(\xi, y_1 + y_2) + \beta(x_1 + x_2,\eta)= \beta(\xi,y_1)+\beta(\xi,y_2)+\beta(x_1,\eta)+\beta(x_2,\eta)$ because $\beta$ is bilinear. Hence we have $D\beta(x_1 + x_2,y_1+ y_2)(\xi , \eta)=D\beta(x_1,y_1)(\xi , \eta) +D\beta(x_2,y_2)(\xi , \eta)$.